# What purpose does a modem serve?

Tags: networking, modem

My basic understanding is that the Internet is a collection of computer networks joined via routers; i.e. the routers provide the link/gateway from one network to the next.

Also, on a local area network everything you need, hardware wise, to talk other computers can be achieved without modems.

This also applies to communcation *with other networks*—e.g. large commercial, goverment and academic organisations can have many networks—and communication between computers in many cases again without modems.

Knowing that *across network* communication can be done without modems why are modems e.g. consumer DSL type modems needed?

Is it to convert the signal which otherwise normally handled by RJ45 cables or Wi-Fi to a “computer logic containing” signal which can be sent along single core copper wires which were built with circuit switching and telephones in mind?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(RJ45 is a connector type, not a cable type)

Modem, as the name suggests (modulator-demodulator) takes a digital signal (in this case) and modulates it into an analog signal with a carrier wave that can be sent via the desired means of transportation.

Originally data needed to be transported via phone lines. They weren't designed for that and transmitting a digital signal over long distances with questionable quality wires isn't easy. Add to that filtering to only certain frequencies and there's even more problems.

Modems were invented to take a suitable carrier frequency and modulate it with the digital data. Speeds were low until cables became better and new technologies were introduced. The frequency range also limited the speeds. But the plus side: you could just call a number and transmit data without any dedicated cabling. Phone centers wouldn't know it's not a normal phone call since it's audio on the same frequencies as the regular stuff, i.e. speech.

Even today modems are widespread. ADSL is one example, cable TV carries data in many places and some people have local networks using power lines in their house. All modulate the signal. They also make use of multiplexing many signals on the same wire with different frequencies and can adapt to different conditions using different frequency bands. They are designed to handle interference well.

Why do that? Because its affordable. There are areas where having optic cables or other dedicated cabling is usable. But what about the person living 20km from the nearest hub point? Its not cheap to put a new cable just to get a network there. They already have the phone cable so why not use it?

Oh, and WiFi also modulates the signal onto specific frequencies. Only the transmission is not on wires but through radio waves. Even using Ethernet includes modulation, just a different kind.  Since the Ethernet network is not shared with other devices (like modems and the phone handsets) we don't bother calling the Ethernet transceivers "modems".

Comment: nice answer, +1

Comment: Modems aren't the only devices performing modulation/demodulation.  If you want to transmit digital information at all (in this analog world), you need to modulate it, using amplitude, frequency, phase, or a combination of these.  A TTL input is a simple amplitude demodulator: less than x volts is a logic low and more than y volts is logic high.  That's an analog to digital/logic conversion.

Comment: @sawdust Exactly. Just because a device is not called a modem doesn't mean it would function that differently.

Answer (score 3):

In a DSL network, a phone line is typically the physical medium used to carry data. Phone lines carry the signal from houses to equipment owned by carriers for further processing (both voice and data).

The signal output by your network card is a fairly low voltage digital signal. To carry it over the (very often analog) phone line, modulation is performed to encode the digital signal from your network card "into" the analog carrier signal.

Demodulation is the reverse process which takes the analog signal received from the line and yields the low voltage digital signal expected by a NIC.

Modulation is also used in TV and radio to allow the output of video and audio devices such as cameras and mixes to be broadcast over the air or on cable.

Comment: +1 thanks , all good answers. hard to decide which to accept!

Answer (score 3):

#### Shorter answer.

You might be mixing up the technical promise of IP protocol and Ethernet’s flexibility with the physical realities of the world we live in nowadays coupled with the physical limitations of simple networking.

Remember, there is a *physical* aspect to networking—even wireless networking—and a *logical* aspect to networking. Modems are designed to deal with the physical aspects of networking.

More details below, but once you understand a physical infrastructure needs to be built to deliver data that is as reliable as plumbing or electricity, soon you’ll understand why modems are used and needed in many pieces of infrastructure… Not just the home.

#### Longer answer.

Modems are everywhere. Not just at home. Think of a modem not as a “modulator/demodulator” as much as a physical media conversion layer and it all makes sense. Remember, Ethernet cables can only span the length of 100 meters (328 feet) before signal degrades. By that standard, an Ethernet connection can barley span the length of  an average city block in a place like Manhattan.

Knowing that, let’s go on. First you state this:

> My basic understanding is that the Internet is a collection of
>   computer networks joined via routers; i.e. the routers provide the
>   link/gateway from one network to the next.

Slightly wrong assumptions. Yes, there are routers involved. But what kind of routers and what kind of physical media is being used? For main trunk lines that carry the true bulk of Internet traffic, that is not done via the copper in Ethernet cables but rather glass fiber in fiber optic cabling.

Knowing that you already have a media conversion choke point: Converting fiber optic data to copper wire used in Ethernet connections.

But it’s not that simple. You state this:

> Knowing that *across network* communication can be done without modems
>   why are modems e.g. consumer DSL type modems needed?

When you mention DSL that brings up the infrastructure that exists in many locales which is the old school phone system. Which is basically tons of copper wiring in places. And yes, in some places you have fiber optic trunks feeding into copper telco lines but that’s getting too specific.

The general idea is this: The fact that anyone has an Internet connection at all nowadays is not so much based on new technology as much as the efforts that have been made to adapt *old infrastructure* to deal with *new technical needs.*

And when you say this, you basically explain the issue yourself:

> Is it to convert the signal which otherwise normally handled by RJ45
>   cables or Wi-Fi to a “computer logic containing” signal which can be
>   sent along single core copper wires which were built with circuit
>   switching and telephones in mind?

In short, those wires in your walls did not magically appear. And rewiring them to be more efficient—ie: fiber optic for the home—is not an easy matter at all. This is why efforts like Google Fiber are so “magical”: Whatever Google’s true motives are, they are investing millions of dollars to basically rebuild the core physical infrastructure of many locales to be more modernized.

Because if money and labor were no object, then yes, we would all have fiber optic connections to data that would be as common as an electrical outlet. And in some alternate universe where that could happen, perhaps Ethernet would never even exist since all computers would have fiber optic network interfaces readily available.

But that’s not the case.

So what is the world we live in? Telephone companies and cable TV providers are adapting old analog infrastructure to be usable in the modern Internet age. And how do you convert the data coming over a modular telephone jack or a coaxial cable TV connection so it can be usable by a computer?

Do you force computer manufacturers to have a phone jack and a coaxial cable TV connection on each PC? Or do you have a commonly used Ethernet connector that is used for data and then use a modem to convert the data from a modular telephone jack or a coaxial cable TV connection into an Ethernet connection?

And all that doesn’t even touch on wireless data like 3G/4G and why those data systems are not like consumer Wi-Fi.

Remember this: At one point Apple—when Steve Jobs was alive and in charge—was seriously considering rolling out national Wi-Fi—or was it cellular data?—to basically undercut and disrupt… Pretty much everyone and everything in the cell and consumer data world. They abandoned it because logistically it was unfeasible I believe.

Because at the end of the day, the best technology to deliver data is out there. But the best *infrastructure* does not exist. And compromises/adaptations have to be made to allow some form of data communication to exist with the infrastructure we currently have.

Comment: +1 thanks, yes I tried to avoid the bigger picture as - your answer shows - involves lots of moving parts. but is accurate to the state of transporting data over the internet .

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally a [Modem is a *modulator demodulator*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modem) It turns an analog signal into a digital one.

It so happens that most existing longer distance infrastructure analog infrastructure to the premises is analog. Phonelines are (and both dialup and ADSL use analog copper phone) infrascture in different ways as is the cable networks used in docsis cable modems.

Contrast this with fibre optic networking- which is purely digital, and uses an ONT or Optical Network Terminal instead.

If we wanted purely digital transmission we'd need to install new infrascture from end to end, and that gets tricky.

Comment: *"fibre optic networking- which is purely digital"* -- No, it's not.  It has to exist in an analog world.  If you study the optical transceivers you would find out there's modulation and demodulation involved.